# Why the mouse cursor can pass the right border of the screen and not the left one?

Tags: windows, mouse

I have always wondered, why the mouse pointer can be moved a little bit beyond the screen's right and bottom border, and can not be moved at all beyond the left and the upper border?

Unfortunately Print Screen doesn't capture the mouse pointer but I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: If you look VERY CLOSELY on a screen where the actual right edge is visible, the mouse pointer never actually leaves the screen -- there is a 1 or 2-pixel margin visible.  (The same is true for the bottom edge, if you position the cursor tip over the Windows icon so it has a contrasting background.)

Comment: Consider the free version of Gadwin Printscreen, it allows you to capture the mouse cursor or just a rectangular area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the pointer is normally at the top left tip, which is the part that is restricted to the screen boundaries. The rest of the cursor is just a graphic that helps in visually locating this tip. This graphic is not restricted, and in fact can't be - if the cursor graphic was trapped you would not be able to click on the very right or bottom edges of the screen.

If you use a custom cursor, for example a crosshair, where the pointer is not at the top/left corner of the graphic you'll find the graphic can go off the top/left side of the screen too.

Comment: Confirmed. I use a crosshair curser, with the Point exact in the center of the curser, and right or left it stops on the "curser point" not the grafics for the curser.